# Robotics custom search engine

Tags: robotics

I made a google custom search engine: 
[robot cse](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=009577865717141731876%3Agtymb6odhyk&auth=DQAAAOMAAABJPdvJt1AVHRfLMw2AEQaQ7KGrnEvJGzuuUqanqSy941B2zxC4mHKH9O3puT_e6EtoHBFRInW0JjWjAyq04BHD99PeDNr28EdUPphEOvbfxIcpLqH5FK2wNDGjnZMPTgLle1mLGgddCYBh9Yp8im2lF_1Ezgt_aZBOKn_x_xOfwsabLuAF7IHf261KPQlxy9_YjApOYtYThqhCs7ONuKWgAYj21fYxXnF1bNq594mYIXYPb-t6IDvw1xl73JItXV_SFzp89TCvVukDn0y5t9sICCCpPrURVVe5zYU0tmgCRH4m0-KAakR7O_rbyDGSJgs). Any sites I should add to the list.
 http://forum.microchip.com/    
 http://www.avrfreaks.net    
 http://www.societyofrobots.com/robotforum/

Comment: Please make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps http://forums.makezine.com/ and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Maybe the Make forums are too broad in their coverage?